# Member "mul" not found or not visible after argument

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design

I'm a beginner trying to write a Token contract, and I have encountered an error using Solidity 0.4.19. Here is the piece of code with the problem:

```
  function createTokens () payable {
    require(msg.value >0);

    uint256 tokens = msg.value.mul(RATE);
    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].add(tokens);

    owner.transfer(msg.value);
  }
```

This is the error message:

> Member "mul" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup
>   in uint256

Can anyone please offer a tip to fix this, thank you very much?

Answer (score 8):

You stumbled into an advanced pattern.

You could say

```
uint256 tokens = msg.value * RATE;
```

That would do the trick except that it might overflow if the result is ever over 2^256. To make sure that and other nasty things don't ever happen, there is a popular `SafeMath.sol` contract you can use. It's over here: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol

Then you might start out with:

```
import "./SafeMath.sol";

contract myContract {

  using SafeMath for uint256;

  // ... carry on
```

Now, type `uint256` has a method `.mul` that the compiler is looking for.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much :) It worked but I had exactly the same error on the following line, so I replaced .add with + and that seems to work fine. Thanks again

Comment: It's the same idea. If the add method isn't present it's probably because `balances` is cast as something other than `uint256`. Thanks for the accept. ;-)

Comment: Too bad they did put `shl` (shift-left) in there as well...